# Triangular numbers

Tags: combinatorics, reference-request

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangular_number

I am looking at Triangle numbers and how wikipedia arrived at test for "Triangularity" by checking $(\sqrt{8x + 1} - 1)/2$

The article references item 4 but that does not seem to provide any proof.

can someone help me with references?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It comes from solving the equation $$\frac{n(n+1)}{2}=x$$ for $n$, where $x$ and $n$ are non-negative.  The solutions obtained are $$n=\frac{-1\pm \sqrt{1+8x}}{2},$$ and we throw away the negative solution.

Comment: Aaha you are right if we apply the "standard" quadratic formula http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_equation this solves it for me! Cool thanks